# Download the apt-get packages for a raspberry pi OS program in a windows PC

Tags: debian, apt, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi zero W board that I cannot get to connect to wifi

I want to install cmake into it but I am having trouble building cmake 3.21.3 (after a very long compiling process some error similar to "compiler does not support C++11" shows up; not sure what's up with that since it has gcc 8.3.0 which I though supported upto C++14).

If wifi was working on it I could have just done "sudo apt-get install cmake" and be default I think it install cmake 3.13 or something

Is there a way to get just whichever .deb file that "sudo apt-get install cmake" uses, from a windows computer? Is the exact file listed somewhere on a website, and if it is how can I find it? Will I be able to just copy this file over to the raspberry pi os sdcard and install it manually offline?

The OS version is the latest raspberry pi OS desktop version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look up the repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list` with optional entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

This links you to http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/

Now in the `pool` you will find the precompiled `deb`-packages (or source-code as `.tar.gz`), e.g. for `main` - then sorted alphabetically (by letter, then package name, different versions are in the package directory). You will find `cmake` and a set of possible versions right here:

http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/c/cmake/

---

Installation is simple, use

```
 dpkg -i package.deb
```

If it fails, this is usually due to missing dependencies, which will be displayed. The annoying part is now recursively determining, downloading, and installing the dependency packages.
A simple program to find dependencies recursively is `apt-rdepends` - but in your case you would have to install this manually as well and is depends on the current update state of the repository list.

Comment: In the raspberry pi forums I saw a post (https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=232813) where someone said this command would download QT for development [$ sudo apt-get install qt5-default] but I can't find "qt5-default" in the "/pool/main/q/" folder. Does this mean "qt5-default" doesn't exist and even if I manage to get the wifi working I won't be able to install QT using the command given above?

Comment: @user13267 Use `apt show qt5-default`, and search for `Source:`. It hints to `qtbase-opensource-src`, and there it is: http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/q/qtbase-opensource-src/ , i.e. under `/main/q/qtbase-opensource-src/`